# How to display Custom Messages on Flash #2048 ou similar errors?

Tags: apache-flex, security, error-handling, customization

Is there a way to override the #2048 Security Sandbox Violation and display a custom message in Flash Player?

Basically I need to show something like "Opsss! Your connections is broken...".

I'm using Flex 4.6

Best regards. 
Ronaldo

Comment: look up [try...catch](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ed1.html) -> display the custom message when you catch the error

Comment: Profenza, Its not possible. I tried it. The error is a Sandbox Violation.

Comment: you are loading content, right ? if so, there should a listener for sandbox violation, be it using the loader (`loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,displayOoopsMessageInThisHandler);` or sound

Comment: No, I'm connecting to a XML Socket! But, if the connection is behind a firewall, I'd to be able to show a  custom message. Thanks

Comment: I solved the problem. I need to add SecurityErrorEvent listener and on the event: event.stopPropagation();

Comment: @Rigoni Post that as a formal answer to your question.